# Why did I get FATAL EXCEPTION when I test MediaRecorder sample?

Tags: android

I test the sample E:\Android_SDK\samples\android-22\media\MediaRecorder in my real device using Android Studio, I get the following error, why? Is there some bugs in the sample?

BTW, my android verion is 5.1

```
09-28 16:09:31.683  17233-17233/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/Zygote﹕ v2
09-28 16:09:31.683  17233-17233/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
09-28 16:10:06.343  17233-17772/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19
09-28 16:10:06.343  17233-17772/com.example.android.mediarecorder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.android.mediarecorder, PID: 17233
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
            at com.example.android.mediarecorder.MainActivity$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:208)
            at com.example.android.mediarecorder.MainActivity$MediaPrepareTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:200)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Added**

And more, it works well after I remove `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in AndroidManifest.xml, but I don't know why?

Comment: Were you rendering progress bar UI on main thread via background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaRecorder` sample works in `Landscape` mode, and to make it work in `portrait` mode as well you need to add following code in **exact sequence**!

here is the code:-

add this for `portrait` support to `mCamera`

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

and to support `Audio/Video` encoder and `OutputFormat` add this

```
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

so below will your complete method `prepareVideoRecorder`

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_preview)
        mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultCameraInstance();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        // We need to make sure that our preview and recording video size are supported by the
        // camera. Query camera to find all the sizes and choose the optimal size given the


        try {
                // Requires API level 11+, For backward compatibility use {@link setPreviewDisplay}
                // with {@link SurfaceView}
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        // END_INCLUDE (configure_preview)


        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
                CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
        //
        //mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(SufaceView);
        // Step 4: Set output file

        // END_INCLUDE (configure_media_recorder)

        // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and finally you can remove `screenOrientation` from manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

this above code will work in both `orientation` but `Camera` Display always will be `90 degree` so you need to make changes by handling your orientation properly.

Comment: Thanks! I test your code, it works, but I'm very strange why Android SDK give an error sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the problem with above said MediaRecorder Sample but I have added **`"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`** and then the sample project is working fine with landscape mode also

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >>
```

Comment: Thanks!, your code work. But I'm very strange why Android SDK give an error sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should have had the `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` included under the Activity, which tells me you have an outdated sample project in your hands.

Please make sure you are running the latest version of the Sample projects.

Either open the project via

> File > New > Import Sample > type MediaRecorder

or

`git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder.git`

Just tested the sample code with Android 5.1 (API level 22) and it was working fine both on a tablet and a smartphone.

Please keep `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` under Application and don't change it, as that is not what the sample code provides. Template styles are defined under

> res > values > template-styles.xml

and it is defined for both tablet and smartphone.

Comment: I test the code  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder.git, but I get the same error. BTW android:versionCode="1" in the code

Answer (score 0):

It is missing permissions

Add this call in your onCreate at MainActivity.java

```
 if (!checkPermissionFromDevice())
        requestPermission();
```

and insert these two methods into MainActivity.java

```
private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice()
{
    int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int camera_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && camera_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void requestPermission()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```