# Android Video Recording using Media Recorder is Not working

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder, android-videoview, video-recording

I am trying to Record a Video, But It's getting crash at Media Record starts and Media Record Prepare .please  Help Me... Here Is My Code...

```
private boolean startRecording() {
        camera.unlock();
        try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error");
            }
        });
            second=0;
            minute=0;
            recordCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    second++;
                    if(second>=60){
                        second=0;
                        minute++;
                    }
                    recordCount.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",minute,second));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    finish();
                }
            }.start();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            Log.d(TAG, "A");
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            Log.e(TAG, "B");
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        defaultVideoPath= FileManger.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).getAbsolutePath();
//        uriVid = Uri.parse(FileManger.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).getAbsolutePath());
//        defaultVideoPath = getRealPathFromUri(uriVid);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(defaultVideoPath);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(recordingCameraSurface.getWidth(), recordingCameraSurface.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
            Log.v(TAG, "C");
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
            Log.w(TAG, "D");
        mediaRecorder.start();
            Log.e(TAG, "E");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }catch (IllegalStateException t){
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return  false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It's giving like

```
RECORDER_OK﹕ B
MediaRecorder﹕ setOutputFormat called in an invalid state: 4
```

and Here I am Going to next Activity:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(RecordBuyPage.this,CheckAndSaveActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("VIDEOFILEPATH", defaultVideoPath);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and in the next Activity i am getting the path null like:

```
 player.setDataSource(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEOFILEPATH"));
```

I think My Order Of Calling Media Recorder Is Correct But it also getting trouble at:

```
 mediarecoreder.prepare().
```

Please Give Some Valid Solution, I tried a lot From Stack overflow, but it's not working.... I think Video Is Not Recording, because when I passed it through intent it's taking null...

Comment: have you tried below answer?, does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you followed this link of sample code(`Media Recorder`)
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder

and it has some bugs in it to `record media` in `portrait` mode so to fix this issue please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818562/why-did-i-get-fatal-exception-when-i-test-mediarecorder-sample/32988922#32988922)

and in this link you will get your `media path` where it `stored` and you can easily `pass` it to another `activity`. Have a look I hope it helps you.

to get the path of `media` on `stop` `capturing` you can do this on your `CaptureClick` method

```
Log.d("Video file path", CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
                        CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
```

and complete button `OnClickListener`

```
public void onCaptureClick(View view) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // BEGIN_INCLUDE(stop_release_media_recorder)

            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
            isRecording = false;
            releaseCamera();
            Log.d("Video file path", CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
                    CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
            // END_INCLUDE(stop_release_media_recorder)

        } else {

            // BEGIN_INCLUDE(prepare_start_media_recorder)

            new MediaPrepareTask().execute(null, null, null);

            // END_INCLUDE(prepare_start_media_recorder)

        }
    }
```

**Please follow these two links provided above,** it might solve your issue.